# How to open a list of URLs in Firefox or SeaMonkey?

Tags: firefox, seamonkey

I have a list of URLs in a text file, for example,

```
http://url1
http://url2
http://url3
```

I wonder how to open them each in one tab in Firefox (or SeaMonkey), without the hassle of creating a new tab, copying into address bar and hitting return for  each URL?

My OS is Ubuntu 10.10. Both command line and GUI solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 36):

You can save the following to a HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Open Windows</title>
<script>
function openWindow(){
    var x = document.getElementById('a').value.split('\n');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        if (x[i].indexOf('.') > 0)
            if (x[i].indexOf('://') < 0)
                window.open('http://'+x[i]);
            else
                window.open(x[i]);
}
</script>
<style>
html, body
{
    height : 99%;
    width  : 99%;
}

textarea
{
    height : 80%;
    width  : 90%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="a"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Open Windows" onClick="openWindow()">
<input type="button" value="Clear" onClick="document.getElementById('a').value=''">
</body>
</html>
```

Now load the file in Firefox, copy the list of URLs in the textarea and click `Open Windows`.

Comment: Hah... I haven't thought 'bout that one! I usually do it with `firefox \`cat file.txt\`` (as WakiMiko wrote). Anyway using your way will work on all OS. :D

Comment: Now this is what I call "for the win." +1 for platform independence. Would definitely accept this answer. Supported: SeaMonkey, FireFox, IE, Chrome, Safari, etc...Ubuntu, Windows, Mac, etc.

Comment: Technically chrome blocking as pop-ups. But since I need source and I'm running fiddler, you made my day. Thanks a done.

Comment: This is perfect. Is there anyway to add a slight delay, lets say 5 seconds between opening each tab?

Comment: @DomainsFeatured Sure. You could use `setInterval` to iterate over the domains and cancel it once all of them have been processed.

Comment: Hey Dennis, could you post the code here please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894481/how-to-add-delay-to-html-javascript-function I'm not sure how to do that. Would be so grateful!

Comment: Awesome answer, I made a JSFiddle for anyone as lazy as I am - https://jsfiddle.net/y1dgezuL/

Comment: Made a functional and modernized version here -> https://jsfiddle.net/L06mkcvd/

Comment: I recommend changing `for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)` to `for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)` so that the tab order matches the list order. I don't know if it was true in 2012, but Firefox currently opens each new tab immediately to the right of the current tab when using the page above.

Answer (score 34):

A simple

```
firefox $(cat file.txt)
```

should suffice. It will pass each link as an argument to the `firefox` command, as long as every link is separated by whitespace.

Comment: +1. Thanks! That works! I wonder if you happen to know how to do that in SeaMonkey? I tried `seamonkey $(cat urls)`, but only the url in the first line is opened.

Comment: if you're doing this over SSH to something running Xorg, you need to set the display to open firefox window in:
`env DISPLAY=:0 firefox $(cat file.txt)`

Comment: `cat` is not needed, `firefox $(< example-domains.txt)` is more streamlined — see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat and https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/remove-useless-uses-of-cat-or-not

Comment: If the `--new-tab` [flag](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions) is added — `firefox --new-tab $(< example-domains.txt)` — Firefox only appears to open the first tab in the current window. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1789351/598527) for a potential solution (but works on my machine).

Answer (score 11):

On windows you can create a batch file (named say, multiurl.bat):

```
@echo off    
for /F "eol=c tokens=1" %%i in (%1) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %%i
```

and then run `multiurl.bat urls.txt` from the command line and it will load the URLS in new tabs if FireFox is already open, or it will run it and then load the URLS.

Comment: You aren't required to create a .bat file to use the `for` command.

Comment: This is not relevant - the users asks for a solution that will work on Linux machines!

Comment: @TheDevil Come on, this answer took longer than three minutes to test and type. I suggest tfitzgerald keeps this answer up, there might be others interested. I sure won't delete my answer for OS X.

Comment: @TheDevil Yes, he edited his question as I was writing my answer.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg That is correct.  But I don't think I said you are required to...but why would you want to type that whole line each time you wanted to do this?  That is what scripts are for!

Comment: @fitzgerald The user didn't specify how often he plans on using the functionality. If only a single use would be intended, creating a dedicated script is unnecessary. Your answer might leave the impression that a script is required for this to work.

Comment: Yes, the words, "you can" obviously translate to "you must" over the Internet.  Thanks for reminding me though, if you were to do this just in a command prompt you would want to change the `%%i` to just `%i`.  The double percent signs are only for when using the `for` command in a batch file.

Answer (score 8):

On Mac OS X, save the following script as `openurls.sh`, run `chmod +x openurls.sh` in Terminal, and then type `./openurls.sh` from the same directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read line ; do
    open -a Firefox "$line"
done < "/path/to/file-with-urls.txt"
```

Comment: +1. Thanks! Do you also know how to do that for SeaMonkey instead of Firefox?

Comment: @Tim I don't have SeaMonkey to test it. Also, I'm afraid this script opens windows instead of tabs, sorry about that.

Comment: This can easily be fixed with changing some settings in Firefox. Go to Edit->Preferences->Tabs and select "Open new window in new tab instead" :)

Comment: @TheDevil Thanks! I guess it's obvious I only use FF for answering questions on SU.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the Firefox profile?

Answer (score 2):

Open your text file in firefox as

```
file:///C:/URLTextFile.txt
```

1. Select the whole link
2. Right click on it
3. Click on "Open Link in new tab"

Comment: Only opens one (ex. the first url from many selected)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [an existing Linux answer](https://superuser.com/a/385218/598527), personally I strongly prefer **opening all pages in the same** (existing, open) browser window. Unfortunately Firefox ([command-line flags](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions)) appears not to accept all the input at once and I had to implement delay (`sleep`) between actions with `xargs` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153337/6404709)):

```
<example-domains.txt xargs -I "%" sh -c '{ firefox --new-tab "%"; sleep 0.25; }'
```

You may be able to use a significantly shorter delay than 0.25 seconds. You can try out the method with a file containing ([about the reserved domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com)):

```
https://example.com/
https://example.net/
https://example.org/
https://example.edu/
```

Comment: xargs 4.9.0, Mozilla Firefox 114.0 (documenting if the method turns out to be not entirely universal and compatible)