# Open a list of URLs each with 20-30s delay

Tags: firefox

I have the following script from a post from Dennis from [this URL](https://superuser.com/questions/385207/how-to-open-a-list-of-urls-in-firefox-or-seamonkey)

It's exactly what i'm looking for but i need to be able to open each url 20 or 30 seconds apart.

```
<script>
function openWindow(){
    var x = document.getElementById('a').value.split('\n');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        if (x[i].indexOf('.') > 0)
            if (x[i].indexOf('://') < 0)
                window.open('http://'+x[i]);
            else
                window.open(x[i]);
}
</script>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Of what user is post 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid freezing the whole browser (with a delay function) you can use `setTimeOut` to execute a function 20000 milliseconds apart.

All the `setTimeout` are executed right after each other. There is a function scheduled at  each atTime milliseconds. Each loop the atTime parameter is increased by 20000 (20 seconds). After that your page stays dormant and the setTimeout functions are executed at the assigned times.

Note the `setTimeout("window.open('" + site + "')", atTime);`. We can't do `setTimeout(window.open(site), atTime);` because the function between setTimeout is evaluated at execution time and the variable `site` will have the last value of the loop. So we do a `setTimeout("window.open('xxx')", atTime);` where xxx changes in the loop. This way the variable is set in the execution command. (Hope i'm clear enough)

Here is the script:

```
<script>
function openWindow(){
    var x = document.getElementById('a').value.split('\n');
    atTime = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (x[i].indexOf('.') > 0) {
        site = x[i];
        if (x[i].indexOf('://') < 0) { site = 'http://' + x[i]; }
        setTimeout("window.open('" + site + "')", atTime);
        atTime += 20000;
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: it was the script by Dennis. 

> If i paste in multiple urls in the box of the script i need for example.

open www.google.com
wait 20 seconds
open www.bing.com
wait 20 seconds
open www.yahoo.com

and so on through the list that has been pasted in.

Hope it makes sense as my English is not very good and this is my first time with HTML.

Thankyou

Comment: Then you can use the `sleep` function in my second code in my answer.

Comment: Thankyou Rik I'll give it a go. This is my first ever HTML edit , wish me luck. :)

Comment: It's not working as i hoped as a blank white window opens every 20 seconds with " firefox not responding " and it's not until 20 seconds after the last frozen window opens that i then suddenly get all the frozen pages to load all the URLs at once. :( If you have any ideas i will be back on tomorrow to reply. thanks

Comment: Yeah, already said the delay-function was not recommended. I changed my answer to a function where there is no freezing of the browser.

Comment: That Worked , You have inspired me to learn code. :)